# Add a text value to Material UI Date Picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on a site that contains job history information, I am using Material UI 5.11 in order to select the dates for when they started and ended the job.

I would like to add an option to select " present " in the material ui date picker to represent current employer.

How would I configure the material ui form to allow for customized input?

This is what I have got so far:

So far I have tried adding text to the TextField in render input, however I would prefer if I could modify the modal that pops up instead.

```
 <DatePicker
                    views={["year", "month"]}
                    label="End "
                    minDate={dayjs("2012-03-01")}
                    maxDate={dayjs("2023-06-01")}
                    value={
                      store.exp1end
                        ? dayjs(store.exp1end.slice(1, 8)).toDate()
                        : dayjs()
                    }
                    onChange={(newValue) => {
                      updateExp1end(newValue);
                    }}
                    open={openEnd1}
                    onOpen={() => setOpenEnd1(true)}
                    onClose={() => setOpenEnd1(false)}
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                      <TextField
                        {...params}
                        onClick={(e) => setOpenEnd1(true)}
                        helperText={"Current month for present"}
                        sx={{
                          marginTop: "-.70em",
                          "@media (max-width: 920px)": {
                            marginTop: "2rem !important;",
                          },
                        }}
           />
       )}        
   />
```

[image]

Comment: For customized input you can get inspiration from this [MUI docs page](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/custom-components/). It is dedicated to customizing calendar subcomponents. You can add a custom button for the **Present** option and display the status of "Present" with text in a custom component.

Comment: thank you good sir, that was exactly what I was looking for. I ended up passing in a custom action bar through the Components prop.